# Child change when parent is hovered over

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to get a child element to change when the parent is hovered. I also want an attribute of that parent to change as well. I am trying to get the background color of `#action` to change and the color of the `a` or `h1` to change when `action` is hovered over. Is this possible?

here is the html

```
<section id="action" class="general">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="#"><h1>This text</h1></a>
    </div>
</section>
```

and here is the css. CSS is built using SASS that is why it is structured like that.

```
#action {
    background-color: $bgLight;
    border-top: 1px solid #252525;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;

    a {
        text-decoration: none;

        h1 {
            margin: 0;
            color: $colorLight;
            font-weight: 300;
            text-align: center;
        }
    }
}

#action:hover a {
    background-color: #76A7D1;
    color: $colorDark;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
#action {
    background-color: $bgLight;
    border-top: 1px solid #252525;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;

    a {
        text-decoration: none;

        h1 {
            margin: 0;
            color: $colorLight;
            font-weight: 300;
            text-align: center;
        }
    }
}

#action:hover{
    background-color: #76A7D1;
    a{
       h1{
          color: $colorDark;
       }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same as @Alessandro Minoccheri suggested but in a less verbose way which I like particularly:

```
#action {
    background-color: $bgLight;
    border-top: 1px solid #252525;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;

    a {
        text-decoration: none;

        h1 {
            margin: 0;
            color: $colorLight;
            font-weight: 300;
            text-align: center;
        }
    }
    &:hover{
        background-color: #76A7D1;
        a{
           h1{
              color: $colorDark;
           }
         }
    }

}
```

The **&** within **#action** refers to the parent element, in other words to **#action** itself.

I like this approach because everything gets self contained within one style declaration and is less repetitive.

It is like saying: "... and when this element is hovered apply these styles to it, and these styles to a and h1".

One small comment regarding your markup @zachstames: a (anchor element) is an inline content element, while h1 (header of level 1) is a block element. According to the [W3C specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3) an inline element should not contain block elements but only data.

Hope it helps.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GTPBK/)

You are able to make this:

```
#action:hover {
    background: yellow;
}

#action:hover a {
    background-color: #76A7D1;
    color: white;
}
```

As you can see I repeat the use of the pseudo-class `#action:hover`. I'm saying:

"When action is hover, change it's backgroud **AND** when action is hover, change the background and the font color of the `a` element".

Hope I've helped.

Be good,
Leonardo